# regex: max-age value

Tags: regex, hsts

I'm trying to validate a HSTS header.

There are two scenarios that need testing for:

1. Multiple Max-age values e.g `max-age=342343; max-age=234234`

The following works ONLy when there is no "`;`" value between the two max-ages.  Which is a problem....

2. The second is where the Max-age contains digits and other characters e.g `max-age=324A` or `max-age=534A;`

   ```
   var string = 'max-age=3423A42; preload';

   var multipleMaxAge = string.match(/max-age=([0-9]+)/gi).length;
   var invalidMaxAge = string.match(/max-age=(.*\D+.*$);?/gi);

   if (invalidMaxAge){
      alert("Max-age Can only be digits... error");
   }
   if (multipleMaxAge != 1){
      alert("Multiple Maximum Ages!");
   }
   ```

How would I get the regex to pattern match with or without the `;` at the end...

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to match the complete line `max-age=342343; max-age=234234`? or only this much `max-age=342343;`

Comment: I would like to match both, but in two different strings.

Comment: wont `max-age=(?:[0-9]+);?` work?

Comment: Check :- https://regex101.com/r/uL1cE5/2

Answer (score 1):

Try `max-age=([0-9]+)[\s;]`.

The `[\s;]` means that the next character after your number will be a space or a `;`.

It should fix the issue you have with random letters, too.

Comment: @user3853149 I assumed your data might be space-delimited like: `max-age=342342     preload`

Comment: It is space deliminated, but the ";" is optionional. 

It could be either
`max-age=34234; preload` OR `max-age=3243242 preload`

Comment: @user3853149 Then the regex should work (did you try it???). The `[]` means char class, and  it is essentially an `OR` for single characters. `\s` signifies space btw.